# How to reshape a list of lists into a data frame for csv export

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to stack a list of lists on top of each other into a data frame:

I currently have a list that is 30 elements long and each element has two elements in it. When I export it to CSV I want the 2 element to have a row each, I can achieve this if I restrict it to the first 10 rows:

[image]

When I add the new rows, it combines the 2 elements into one:

[image]

```
data=pd.DataFrame(data=zip(data[0:10],data[10:20]))

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.set_axis(headers, axis=1)
df.to_csv('GFG.csv', mode='w', index=False, header=True)
```

I used the above code, so I just tried to zip them together. How would I stack these and maintain the first configuration?

Comment: If it works for the first 10, why can't you just do all 30 in the same manner? Why zip two slices of the same list and not just process the whole list? `pd.DataFrame(list_of_elements).T` works fine for me.

Comment: @acrobat The header is only 10 cells long.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok gotya, so I'm assuming your 30 element list is 3 sequences of your 10 header items back to back.

You can slice this list into your 10-item groups and concatenate the dataframes created for each one.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data=data[i:i+10]).T for i in range(0,len(data),10)], ignore_index=True).set_axis(headers, 1)
```